# How can I detect a user submission of a search field in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I've got a search bar in a jQM/phonegap/cordova Android app.

How on earth do I detect when the user presses 'enter' or 'done' or whatever, so I can submit the search??

Do I have to build a custom key detector, or is there an event for this?

So frustrating - I can't find this in the docs anywhere....

Cheers all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would wrap the field in a form element ie:

```
<form id="foo">
<input type="text" />
</form>
```

Then to trigger an event when "the user presses the equivalent of 'return' on a PC keyboard i.e. 'go' or 'done', or whatever the OS has called it" you can use

```
$('#foo').submit(function(){
    //do stuff
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use the same code you would in a "normal" HTML application. Since you are using jQuery Mobile, you can use jQuery. If the field had an id of foo, you could use

```
$("#foo").on("click", function() {
//do stuff here
});
```

Comment: That's the problem though - they're not clicking anything. There's no discrete submit button. I want to start the search when the user presses the equivalent of 'return' on a PC keyboard i.e. 'go' or 'done', or whatever the OS has called it.